# The User Profile service failed the sign-in

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, user-accounts

I have a Windows 8.1 Pro Dell 15R Laptop and I am trying to create a local user but when I initially log on, I says, "The User Profile service failed the sign-in."
I asked Answer Desk and I couldn't afford their services.

Any idea to help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bug in Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 (KB2932965) can cause this (see the [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/838232/update-kb2932965-creates-sqm-files-in-the-default-user-profile-that-prevent-new-local-user-accounts-to-login-to-windows)). I worked around the problem by deleting `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon`; however, if you wanted to play it safe, you could reset the permissions on that folder to inherit from parent instead.

Comment: thanks.more info from my case. replace all children permission from C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft folder if there are no VSCommon  (Win server 2012)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this: 
[You receive a "The User Profile Service failed the logon” error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215)

1. Start your laptop in safe mode
2. Fix the user account profile: Open the registry editor
3. Find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
4. Find the folder that begins with S-1-5 (SID key)
5. Find the ProfileImagePath entry in the details pane
6. If two folders are named  S-1-5..., but one ends with .bak, add .ba at the end of the name of the folder that doesn't end with .bak
7. From the folder name that ends with .bak, remove .bak
8. Rename the folder from step 6 to .bak, instead of .ba
9. Double-click the folder without .bak in the details pane, double-click RefCount, type 0, and then click OK
10. Repeat step 9 for **State**
11. Restart the laptop

Answer (score 0):

The Default profile `C:\Users\Default` may be corrupted. Using an administrator account, try to restore it to a previous version, or failing that, copy it over from a known good installation on another PC.

**Sources:**

[User Profile Service Failed User Profile Could Not Be Loaded on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/964713/user-profile-service-failed-user-profile-could-not-be-loaded-on-windows-10/965530#comment1331106_965530)

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-restore-cusersdefault-user-after-it-was/7adab233-595d-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/windows-10-signin-error-user-profile-service/b71eb998-3a61-4958-b40b-bcc22e19dfe9?page=2

Comment: If you haven't seen, this was fixed long ago. Thanks for the contribution.