# User Profile Service Failed User Profile Could Not Be Loaded on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles

I've upgraded to Windows 10 in the last few weeks, and I had to update some drivers to get things working. Aside from that, it has been great.

Now I am trying to create a new user via the Settings panel. When I go to log in, it says

> User Profile Service Failed User Profile Could Not Be Loaded.

I have tried making just a local account and an a Microsoft account, but still receive the same message.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is fairly simple (found it on reddit):

Just copy the Default folder (in C:\Users) from another Windows 10 computer and, after you rename your problematic Default folder to something like DefaultOLD (just to keep it for safety reasons), paste it in your Users folder.

To make sure that you won't have problems with permissions of the "implant" folder, just transfer it via a FAT/FAT32 formatted usb stick (those filesystems don't have permissions).

Comment: See also http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-restore-cusersdefault-user-after-it-was/7adab233-595d-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5 if you don't have access to another Win10 computer.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue. After spending some time i found the following solution.

> Description: windows 10; upgrade from 7.
>   Issue: unable to login to
>   new accounts.( profile service error)
>
> Solution:
>
> 1. as admin: rename "c:/Users/default" folder to default.bak
> 2. Go to c:/windows.old/Users/. Copy Default folder to c:/Users/
> 3. Logoff and login to new account( no more profile service error)